# Flutter get current Date format style

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I searched a lot without finding a solution.

I would like to get the current Date time format by locale (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)
For example, if my locale zone in the U.S. I would like to get "MDY" if Europe "DMY" and so on.

Is there a way to get this?

Comment: Do you really want to get a format by locale, or do you want to get the user's preferred format based their device configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and try this:

```
DateFormat.yMd(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode).format(date);
```

Comment: Maybe I was not completely clear. My goal is NOT to have the date formatted.
I would like to have the current date format style. So I need to have something that specify which is the current order of day, month and year based on the locale or zone set in the device.

Comment: You can achieve this by using i18n. You'll have to write the corresponding pattern for each locale accepted in your app. Then depending on the current locale used by the device you can extract the correct pattern and apply your need

Answer (score 0):

Just simply give the formate style and then fetch it..

```
DateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dateTimeSymbolMap`:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbols.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  var dateTimeSymbolMap2 = dateTimeSymbolMap()['en'] as DateSymbols;
  print(dateTimeSymbolMap2.DATEFORMATS); // prints [EEEE, MMMM d, y, MMMM d, y, MMM d, y, M/d/yy]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this small utility method to decide how to order the Month and Day input fields. Basically, you pass your current locale to the stadard format and then parse the `pattern` as you like.

```
///Returns `true` if Month goes first for the current locale in the standard time format
  /// (US for example), or `false` otherwise (Europe for example)
  static bool isMonthGoesFirst(BuildContext context){
    final localFormat = DateFormat.yMd(Localizations.localeOf(context).toString());

    return localFormat.pattern?[0]  == 'M';
  }
```